# Setting up apache solr in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, lucene, solr

I am trying to set up Solr in eclipse by following the instructions here: http://hokiesuns.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-up-apache-solr-in-eclipse.html.

The distribution of Solr that I downloaded does not have WEB-INF directory. I have added the jars that I found in lib to build path. However I get invalid run configuration error.

Can anyone who has Solr set up in eclipse please confirm their settings and configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had not extracted the war.

As Jem pointed out , the .war exists in dist directory. However dist directory itself doesnt exists in the downloaded source :). 
You need to do

```
ant dist
```

in the apache folder to get this.

Hope that helps someone else. I was able to get solr up and running using the command line as well as eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

here's something that might help from a quick googling: In this sort of configuration Maven proves a life savior. Looking for a maven archetype (predefined project structure) I've found [this](http://sourcesense.github.com/solr-packager/). So in an empty dir try to run the `mvn archetype:generate` command they are quoting and finally if you are using eclipse run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` for the eclipse specific files so you can do `Import` > `Existing Maven Projects` from eclipse.

Comment: Thanks!.I am still getting my head arnd the process. Hopefully after spending some time with it I would understand all the steps I am doing now. But for now this is what I understand :
1] Create a new directory in eclipse .
2] Go to the directory in terminal and while connected to internet run the command: mvn archetype:generate.
3] Select Choose archetype:
 local -> solr-standalone-archetype
4] This should have a pre set up project in my eclipse workspace and I can use port 8080 to run the server. This seem to use tomcat instead of jetty, where can I find the configuration for the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the .war file in dist. It has a WEB-INF directory.

So extract the war file and use the files in the lib directory.

For this example I had to make a "classes" directory in WEB-INF

Comment: Hi Jem, Can you please provide me a link where you are dnloading solr from . what is "dist". I cannot find the .war file anywhere .

Comment: it seems like I need to do ant dist to have the war and jars populated